# Replacing string with variable in bash when variable starts with special characters

Tags: bash, variables, sed, replace

Replacing a string with the contents of a variable using *sed* by enclosing the search expression with double (") instead of single (') quotes is well documented.

```
$ astring="Liftoff in [sec]"
$ for s in 3 2 1; do echo $astring | sed -e "s/\[sec\]/$s/"; done
Liftoff in 3
Liftoff in 2
Liftoff in 1
```

However, how do I conduct the above replacement if the variable content starts with special characters? For example, the variable contents could start with a period forwardslash (./), which is often the case if local file paths are passed as variables?

```
for s in ./3 ./2 ./1; do echo $astring | sed -e "s/\[sec\]/$s/"; done
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unknown option to `s'
```

Comment: Here's the problem: `s` should not contain the replacement value; it needs to contain a portion of the `sed` script that will make the desired replacement. You don't pass a variable to `sed`; you dynamically generate a `sed` script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use another delimiter :

```
for s in ./3 ./2 ./1; do echo "$s" | sed -e "s|\[sec\]|$s|"; done
```

to avoid conflict with your input

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular use case, there is no need to use `sed`, and the native bash solution is simpler, more efficient, and less fiddly (because you don't need to worry about delimiters or other special characters in the replacement string):

```
$ for s in ./3 ./2 ./1; do echo "${astring/\[sec\]/$s}"; done
Liftoff in ./3
Liftoff in ./2
Liftoff in ./1
```

See the list of bash parameter expansion syntaxes in the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).