# Substituting keyword in string with multi-line variable via sed

Tags: bash, variables, sed, replace, multiline

*Note: The following question is related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894339/replacing-string-with-variable-in-bash-when-variable-starts-with-special-charact/46898060#46898060), but both the focus of the question and the format of the input variable are different (i.e., contents of a multi-line file). Thus, the correct solution is likely different as well.*

It appears that replacing a keyword in a string with a multi-line variable via `sed` works as long as said variable contains explicit newline characters (`\n`).

```
$ target="foo \n bar \n baz"
$ echo "qux\nquux" > file
$ solution=$(cat file)
$ echo "$solution"
qux\nquux
$ echo $target | sed -e "s|bar|$solution|"
foo \n qux
quux \n baz
```

However, when I open the file `file` in a text editor and substitute the newline character with a linebreak, the replacement with *sed* fails.

```
# Newline character was manually replaced with linebreak in texteditor.
$ solution=$(cat file)
$ echo "$solution"
qux
quux
$ echo $target | sed -e "s|bar|$solution|"
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command
```

How do I have to change the *sed*-command to conduct the sought substitution when the input variable that does not have explicit newline characters?

Comment: Don't use sed for anything other than basic text replacements, use awk or perl which accept variables as arguments and save yourself tons of trouble.

Comment: @123 Right, but the above text replacement appears fairly basic to me. The issue is that newline characters and linebreaks are handled differently, and I don't know how to circumvent this issue.

Comment: well sed doesn't support literal newlines in replacement so obviously it isn't basic enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Introduction/Setup

`sed` is not necessarily the appropriate tool for this particular job. Consider the below options -- the samples for each of which expect the following setup:

```
# Run this before testing any of the code below
source='bar'
target='This string contains a target: <bar>'
solution='This has
multiple lines
and /slashes/ in the text'
```

...and each of which will emit the following output:

```
This string contains a target: <This has
multiple lines
and /slashes/ in the text>
```

Note that with `sed`, you would need to choose a delimiter that isn't used for the expression (thus, with `s/foo/bar/`, neither `foo` nor `bar` can contain a `/`); the below answers both avoid this limitation.

---

#### Shell-Builtin Parameter Expansion

The shell can perform the relevant substitution with only [built-in string manipulation functionality](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100):

```
result=${target//$source/$solution}
echo "$result"
```

---

#### Perl One-Liners As A `sed` Alternative

For longer input strings where the shell's built-in matching is inappropriate, you might also consider a perl one-liner, as described in [BashFAQ #21](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021):

```
in="$source" out="$solution" perl -pe 's/\Q$ENV{"in"}/$ENV{"out"}/g' <<<"$target"
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. You convinced me that Bash's built-in parameter expansion is the appropriate tool to use here.